PostgreSQL , about index skip scan in PostgreSQL
Env
PostgreSQL 13 AWS RDS
Question
if PostgreSQL supports index skip scan or index scan DESC operations.
can i use it?
My expectation is that this query could be faster if it used an index skip scan,
but it seems to insist on a range scan.
and, I also have questions about similar cases where an Index Scan Descending order is needed.
Query
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ,buffers, COSTs ,VERBOSE)
SELECT    INVOICEYM
        , ACCOUNTID
        , CATEGORYCODE
        , SUM(invoiceitemfee) AS TOTAL
        FROM bill_table
    WHERE INVOICEYM = '202407'
        AND KEYSORTORDER = 1
        AND ACCOUNTID = '064199638225'
    GROUP BY INVOICEYM
        , ACCOUNTID
        , CATEGORYCODE

Index columns (PK)



Order
Column Name
Condition




1
invoiceym
=


2
accountid
=


3
invoiceid



4
lineitemid



5
keybillingitemid



6
keysortorder
=


7
operation




raw DATA
INVOICEYM = '202407' AND  ACCOUNTID = '064199638225'



Conditions
Rows




KEYSORTORDER = 1
25


KEYSORTORDER = 2
68,191


KEYSORTORDER = 3
642,828



Table rows 328,431,900
Disk Space 313G
Rel Size   179G
EXPLAIN PLAN
GroupAggregate  (cost=145951.54..145973.14 rows=960 width=41) (actual time=27155.552..27155.564 rows=25 loops=1)
  Output: invoiceym, accountid, categorycode, sum(invoiceitemfee)
  Group Key: bill_table.invoiceym, bill_table.accountid, bill_table.categorycode
  Buffers: shared hit=20 read=28621
  I/O Timings: read=26817.993
  ->  Sort  (cost=145951.54..145953.94 rows=960 width=41) (actual time=27155.542..27155.544 rows=25 loops=1)
        Output: invoiceym, accountid, categorycode, invoiceitemfee
        Sort Key: bill_table.categorycode
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        Buffers: shared hit=20 read=28621
        I/O Timings: read=26817.993
        ->  Index Scan using bill_table_pkey on public.bill_table  (cost=0.70..145903.99 rows=960 width=41) (actual time=12870.225..27155.436 rows=25 loops=1)
              Output: invoiceym, accountid, categorycode, invoiceitemfee
              Index Cond: ((bill_table.invoiceym = '202407'::bpchar) AND ((bill_table.accountid)::text = '064199638225'::text) AND (bill_table.keysortorder = 1))
              Buffers: shared hit=20 read=28621
              I/O Timings: read=26817.993
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning Time: 0.125 ms
Execution Time: 27155.602 ms


Index skip scan isn't supported by default (even in later versions) but it can be emulated with a recursive CTE (easier to do if values are not null).
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   (SELECT col FROM tbl ORDER BY col LIMIT 1)  -- parentheses required
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col > t.col ORDER BY col LIMIT 1)
   FROM t
   WHERE t.col IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT col FROM t WHERE col IS NOT NULL;

A variant also allows to do this on multiple columns (like this)
Some research has been done to implement it natively but they could not agree on how...
A project based on postgres also made their own implementations.
